# Order 2 tables by the same field in each table, mysql, classic asp

Tags: mysql, asp-classic

I am trying to order data from 2 tables to display in one list also based on the id's from a third table.

Table 3 contains ID's to the other 2 tables.

```
e_allocation table
------------------
eid, sid, iid

5, 1234, NULL

5, NULL, 1234
```

table 1 and 2 are tables of similar data.

```
i_status table
--------------
iid, status

1234, Complete

1235, Complete

1236, Not Complete
```

```
s_status table
--------------
sid, status

1234, Complete

1235, Not Complete

1237, Not Complete
```

```
objCon.Execute ("SELECT a.sid, a.iid, b.status AS istats, c.status AS sstats
FROM e_allocation a LEFT JOIN i_status b ON a.iid=b.iid LEFT JOIN s_status c
ON a.sid=c.sid WHERE a.eid = '5' ORDER BY b.status Desc, c.status Desc")
```

So Currently I can get the data from the database but it obviously orders table b first and then c second. I need these ordered as joined.

Currently returning `(Table=I or S, Record ID=1234, Status = Complete or Not Complete)`:

```
I:1234:Complete

I:1235:Complete

I:1236:Not complete

S:1234:Complete

S:1235:Not Complete

S:1237:Not Complete
```

I'm trying to get:

```
I:1234:Complete

S:1234:Complete

I:1235:Complete

S:1235:Not Complete

I:1236:Not complete

S:1237:Not Complete
```

```
while not objDb.EOF
    sid = objDb("id")
    iid = objDb("iid")
    if sid <>"" then datlst = datlst &"S:"& sid &":"&objDb("sstats")&",<BR>"
    if iid <>"" then datlst = datlst &"I:"& iid &":"&objDb("istats")&",<BR>"
    objDb.MoveNext
Wend
response.write datlst
```

Any pointers in the right direction greatly appreciated?
Thanks

Comment: I honestly can't see how the I' or S' is being generated by your SQL statement, please cut and paste the output you are actually seeing on the screen and what you want to see.

Comment: The I or S is just showing which table the data came from so the person knows what type it is.

Comment: OK, so your sort is effectively in the asp code - sorry but someone else will have to help you with that.

Comment: Thanks Mandy, if it can be done in the sql statement then i'm quite open to suggestions, i've only done it that way to get a result, albeit not the correct one! I do need to know which table its come from though i_status or s_status.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my attempt.

```
create table e_allocation (eid int, sid int, iid int);
insert into e_allocation select 5, 1234, NULL;
insert into e_allocation select 5, NULL, 1234;
insert into e_allocation select 5, 1235, NULL;
insert into e_allocation select 5, NULL, 1235;
insert into e_allocation select 5, 1236, NULL;
insert into e_allocation select 5, NULL, 1236;

create table i_status (iid int, status varchar(25));
insert into i_status select 1234, 'Complete';
insert into i_status select 1235, 'Complete';
insert into i_status select 1236, 'Not Complete';

create table s_status (sid int, status varchar(25));
insert into s_status select 1234, 'Complete';
insert into s_status select 1235, 'Not Complete';
insert into s_status select 1237, 'Not Complete';

SELECT
  case when a.sid is null then 'I' else 'S' end as iors,
  ifnull(a.sid,a.iid) as id,
  ifnull(b.status,c.status) as status
FROM e_allocation a LEFT JOIN i_status b ON a.iid=b.iid LEFT JOIN s_status c
ON a.sid=c.sid
WHERE a.eid = '5' and (b.status is not null or c.status is not null)
ORDER BY id, iors
```

Another time please do provide the CREATE TABLE etc. statements so we don't have to type them in.

Comment: Many thanks MandyShaw for your prompt and pretty spot on replay to my very badly explained issue ;o), that pretty much did what i was after, I just had to change the ORDER BY to ORDER BY status Desc, id, iors.